# embedding font in visual studio 2015

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, fonts

I have a custom font .ttf and and .otf file that I have added to my font folder in my mvc project.  How do I call these from CSS?  Seen some articles talk about opening font managers or html designer but I can't see anything to embed these so they work on all browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already added your custom font to the fonts folder in Visual Studio.

Now all you have to do is point to your font in the @font-face rule:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "MyCustomFont.ttf";
        font-style: normal;
        src: url(../fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf); /*if IE */
        src: local("MyCustomFont"), url("../fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */
}
```

If you need another font, just add another @font-face rule

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "MyCustomFont2.otf";
        font-style: normal;
        src: url(../fonts/MyCustomFont2.otf); /*if IE */
        src: local("MyCustomFont2"), url("../fonts/MyCustomFont2.otf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */
}
```

This approach should work for all browsers.

Source:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1589195.aspx?Adding+a+font+to+use+in+visual+studio

Comment: ah thanks, I had seen that but other posts were saying that you needed to add it through VS it self for something.  I don't need to add the otf file then?

Comment: and that goes in site.css yeah?

Comment: @JQuery you still need to add the .tff and .otf files to the font folder via visual studio (or via the fonts folder in your solution directory) but the code obviously goes in your css file, from what you told me it looks this file is called site.css. Just make sure the path to your fonts folder is correct, by default that path I gave in the example should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to do I need to add the otf to the @font-face... also?

Comment: Ah i see, you want to know if you can use more than one font at once? Or are the .tff and .otf files of the same font?

Comment: no, I want to check if I need to load them both? Yes, they are for the same font but wasn't sure if I need to load both or not

Comment: Nope, if both files are the same font just add the .otf file as its a newer format so most likely contains more features than the .tff file.

Comment: No problem, see this question for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/96390/difference-between-otf-open-type-or-ttf-true-type-font-formats